# Neo4j - UNION of 3 different queries

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

I have a problem with one composed query, which has three parts.

1. Get direct friends
2. Get friends of friends
3. Get others - just fill up space to limit

So it should always return limited users, ordered by direct friends, friends of friends and others. First two parts are very fast, no problem here, but last part is slow and it's getting slower while db is growing on size. There are indexes on Person.number and Person.createdAt.

Does anyone have an idea how to improve or rewrite this query, to be more performant?

```
MATCH (me:Person { number: $number })-[r:KNOWS]-(contact:Person { registered: "true" }) WHERE contact.number <> $number AND (r.state = "contact" OR r.state = "declined")
    MATCH (contact)-[:HAS_AVATAR]-(avatar:Avatar { primary: true })
    WITH contact, avatar
    RETURN contact AS friend, avatar, contact.createdAt AS rank
    ORDER BY contact.createdAt DESC
  UNION
    MATCH (me:Person { number: $number })-[:KNOWS]-(friend)-[:KNOWS { state: "accepted" }]-(friend_of_friend:Person { registered: "true" }) WHERE NOT friend.username = 'default' AND NOT (me)-[:KNOWS]-(friend_of_friend)
    MATCH (friend_of_friend)-[:HAS_AVATAR]-(avatar:Avatar { primary: true })
    OPTIONAL MATCH (friend_of_friend)-[rel:KNOWS]-(friend)
    RETURN friend_of_friend AS friend, avatar, COUNT(rel) AS rank
    ORDER BY rank DESC
  UNION
    MATCH (me:Person { number: $number })
    MATCH (others:Person { registered: "true" }) WHERE others.number <> $number AND NOT (me)-[:KNOWS]-(others) AND NOT (me)-[:KNOWS]-()-[:KNOWS { state: "accepted" }]-(others:Person { registered: "true" })
    MATCH (others)-[:HAS_AVATAR]->(avatar:Avatar { primary: true })
    OPTIONAL MATCH (others)-[rel:KNOWS { state: "accepted" }]-()
    WITH others, rel, avatar
    RETURN others AS friend, avatar, COUNT(rel) AS rank
    ORDER BY others.createdAt DESC
  SKIP $skip
  LIMIT $limit
```

Here are some profiles:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LfNww.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0EO0r.png

Final solution is to break down the whole query into three and call them separately, in our case it won't reach 3rd query in 99% and first two are super fast. And it seems that even if it reach 3rd stage, it is still fast, so maybe UNION was slowing the whole thing down the most.

```
const contacts = await this.neo4j.readQuery(`...
if (contacts.records.length < limit){
  const friendOfFriend = await this.neo4j.readQuery(`...
  if (contacts.records.length + friendOfFriend.records.length < limit){
    const others = await this.neo4j.readQuery(`...

merge all results
```

Comment: Can you run a PROFILE on this query, expand all elements of the resulting plan (button with the double down arrow in the lower right of the result pane) and add the image to your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing a lot of work in that third query before the limit. You may want to move the ordering and LIMIT up sooner.

It's also going to be more efficient to pre-match to the friends (and friends of friends) in a single MATCH pattern, we can use `*0..1` as an optional relationship to a potential next node.

And just a bit of style advice, I find it a good idea to reserve plurals for lists/collections and otherwise use singular, as you will only have a single one of those nodes per row.

Try this out for the third part:

```
  MATCH (me:Person { number: $number })
  OPTIONAL MATCH (me)-[:KNOWS]-()-[:KNOWS*0..1 { state: "accepted" }]-(other:Person {registered:"true"})
  WITH collect(DISTINCT other) as excluded
  MATCH (other:Person { registered: "true" }) WHERE other.createdAt < dateTime() AND other.number <> $number AND NOT other IN excluded
  WITH other
  ORDER BY other.createdAt DESC
  SKIP $skip
  LIMIT $limit
  MATCH (other)-[:HAS_AVATAR]->(avatar:Avatar { primary: true })
  WITH other, avatar, size((other)-[:KNOWS { state: "accepted" }]-()) AS rank
  RETURN other AS friend, avatar, rank
```

If we know the type of `createdAt` then we can add a modification that may trigger index-backed ordering which could improve this.

Comment: createdAt is datetime

This improved performance a bit, but still it's very slow.

Comment: I just added a change to the query that I THINK should engage the index-backed ordering. Give that a try, and see if you can get a PROFILE of this.

Comment: Seems very similar in result, added another profile.

Comment: One more question, how can I achieve to get only 50 results from those unions, now I can see a lot more results. Is there something like LIMIT on UNIONS? Because it seems limit is applied only to last query.

Comment: Thank you for your tips, after all I decompose this query into three, calling them separately and only if necessary (if previous result count is lower then limit 50), calling next one. Surprisingly from statistic it seems like 99% of users will not reach phase 3 and if so, it's super fast. So perhaps that union was slowing down the whole thing.

Comment: Unfortunately post-union processing isn't supported at this time, so any LIMITs or other operations can only affect the given subquery, it can't be applied to the unioned result. That said, there are some [techniques for post-UNION processing](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/post-union-processing/) that may help bridge the gap.